# MongoDB query to update nested array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use some nested arrays in **mongoDB** but after several hours fighting with the mongo docs and several other SO questions. I'm thinking I might be doing something terribly wrong. The code below is supposed to update the `confirms` array in the `confirms` array but it won't ever do anything but add new entries. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Events.update({_id: eventId, "confirms.person": personId}, {
    $set: {
        "confirms.$.person": personId,
        "confirms.$.confirmed": isConfirmed,
        "confirms.$.timestamp": new Date()
    }
});
```

And here is a sample of the data I'm trying to operate on, it is currently WRONG because a `personId` should be unique.

```
{
    "_id": "RnE4PaPSZ9FC9MAAQ",
    "eventTitle": "Epic lan PARTY!!!!!",
    "eventDate": "31/07/2015",
    "confirms": [{
        "person": "jjoqekYYaA6n8nYvs",
        "confirmed": true,
        "timestamp": ISODate("2015-07-25T17:15:28.212Z")
    }, {
        "person": "jjoqekYYaA6n8nYvs",
        "confirmed": true,
        "timestamp": ISODate("2015-07-25T17:16:50.485Z")
    }
    }]
}
```

Just in case it might turn out to be relevant, i'm working in meteor js.

Comment: When running your query in the mongo shell using the data you provided (with only one `confirms` array element), the update works perfectly. From a mongodb shell perspective, your query is correct. Try running the query in your db using the shell. If it works then this could be a meteor issue.

Comment: @whyceewhite thanks for that, looked again in all the surrounding code and found my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To update the element of an array which is the variable of a Collection item you could do this:

1. Get the array:

   var arr = Events.findOne({_id: eventId}).confirms;
2. Do your operation
3. Update old array with modified array:

   Events.update({_id: eventId}, {$set: {confirms: arr}});

In case of problems with step 2: you could iterate through the array checking if this.person === personId then set this.confirmed = isConfirmed & this.timestamp = new Date.

There might be ways of operating on arrays within Mongo but this one works for sure.